# How to get contact name for sms conversations?

Tags: android, sms, cursor, contacts

I'm retrieving list of last sms/mms conversations using following query:

```
String[] columns={"type", "address", "date", "body", "conversation_id"};
Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations"), columns,  null, null, "date desc");
```

Can anyone advise me how to get in the same query also contact name? Specifically field `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME`?

I mean, I understand how to get those field in separate query, but I need to get it in the same query as for conversations.

Comment: AFAIK,it's not possible because SMS manager just saves phone number of a person.you need to query it separately to contact api.

Comment: If it would be ordinary SQL I could make smth with `inner join` and get display name in the same query. Why it's impossible in case of ContentResolver's - anyhow we understand that it's based on SQL queries...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Log.i(TAG,"load_contact for "+Phone_numb);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(Phone_numb));
String name = "?";

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, 
    new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

try {
    if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
        contactLookup.moveToNext();
        name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
    } else {
         return Phone_numb;
    }
} finally {
    if (contactLookup != null) {
        contactLookup.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this using this workaround:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("content://sms")
val projection = arrayOf("DISTINCT $THREAD_ID", _ID, ADDRESS, BODY, DATE, TYPE)
val selection = "$THREAD_ID IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY ($THREAD_ID"

contentResolver.query(uri, projection , selection, null, "date DESC")
```

If someone knows better approach, please, share it.