# how to load SMS conversation in listview

Tags: android

Can anyone Explain how to load SMS conversation in listview after using following snippet.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor query = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760802/android-getting-sms-conversation-with-name-or-address

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create Inbox box URI
Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```

Also set permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```